# AutoLayout warnings when using auto sizing collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using self sizing collection view cells and it seems to render it out correctly when I run it however I get a pile of warnings from the compiler all saying the same (running Xcode 12.1)

> contentView of collectionViewCell has translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints false and is missing constraints to the cell, which will cause substandard performance in cell autosizing. Please leave the contentView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints true or else provide constraints between the contentView and the cell.

here is the code for my cell

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.addSubview(content)
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     // this is to enable dynamic height for cells 
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40).isActive = true
       // content is a UILabel I'm using to display text
    content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    content.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
     // imageView is an image for content
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    layer.borderWidth = 1
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Should I worry about these warnings?

Comment: Not really sure how the UI is setup, but try adding left/right anchor for `contentView`

Comment: If I do that that breaks the correct rendering of cells for me

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?